# Pivot Table Records Being Replaced in Laravel 4 Using Sync

Tags: arrays, laravel-4, associative-array

**EDIT**: Thanks to an answer by clod986 which has cleared a few things up concerning the sync() method, I have now modified my code:

```
public function attachDelegates($eventId, $delegates)
{
    $event = $this->find($eventId);

    foreach ($delegates as $key => $value)
    {
        if( ! $event->delegates->contains($key))
        {
            $event->delegates()->attach($key, array(
                'delegate_status_id'    => $value['delegate_status_id'],
                'price'                 => $value['price'],
                'prerequisites'         => $value['prerequisites'],
                'booking_id'            => $value['booking_id']
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

I have 4 tables:

events, delegates, unknowns and a pivot table called delegate_event

In the app you're able to either store multiple unknown delegates on events or a single unknown delegate depending on what button you press.

The problem I'm having is when storing a single unknown delegate for the first time, it works great but as soon as you try to store another single unknown delegate, it will store the delegate and unknown in their respective tables but when it comes to syncing the delegate with the event on the delegate_event table it will replace/update the previous record. Adding multiple unknown delegates works fine.

Here's my code:

```
// Filename: AdminDelegatesController.php
// Selection: 1
public function store()
{
    $delegateData = Input::except(array('delegate_status_id', 'price', 'event_id', 'account_id', 'amount'));
    $eventId = Input::get('event_id');
    $event = $this->event->find($eventId);
    $amount = Input::get('amount');

    if ( ! empty($amount))
    {
        $message = (object) array(
            'title'         => 'Excellent!',
            'content'       => 'The unknown delegates were successfully added to the event.',
            'alert_type'    => 'success'
        );
        $price = Input::get('price') / $amount;
        $data = array(
            'delegate_status_id'    => Input::get('delegate_status_id'),
            'price'                 => $price,
            'prerequisites'         => 'on'
        );
        $unknowns = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++)
        {
            $unknownKey = 'unknown-'.$event->start_date->toDateString().'-'.(int) rand(0,9999);
            $data['key'] = $unknownKey;
            $unknowns[] = $data;
        }
        $unknownData = $this->unknown->storeUnknowns($unknowns);
        $delegates = $this->delegate->storeDelegates(null, $unknownData, $eventId, null);
        $this->event->storeDelegates($eventId, $delegates);
    }
    else
    {
        $message = (object) array(
            'title'         => 'Excellent!',
            'content'       => 'The unknown delegate was added successfully to the event.',
            'alert_type'    => 'success'
        );
        $unknownKey = 'unknown-'.$event->start_date->toDateString().'-'.(int) rand(0,9999);
        $data = array(
            'key'                   => $unknownKey,
            'delegate_status_id'    => Input::get('delegate_status_id'),
            'price'                 => Input::get('price'),
            'prerequisites'         => 'on'
        );
        $unknowns = array($data);
        $unknownData = $this->unknown->storeUnknowns($unknowns);
        $delegate = $this->delegate->storeDelegates(null, $unknownData, $eventId, null);
        $this->event->syncDelegates($eventId, $delegate);
    }
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', $message);
}

// Filename: Unknown.php
// Selection: 1
public function storeUnknowns($unknowns)
{
    if (is_null($unknowns))
    {
        return null;
    }
    foreach ($unknowns as $unknown) {
        $delegate = $this->create(array('key' => $unknown['key']));
        $data[$delegate->id]['delegate_status_id'] = $unknown['delegate_status_id'];
        $data[$delegate->id]['price'] = $unknown['price'];
        $data[$delegate->id]['unknown_id'] = $delegate->id;

        if (empty($unknown['prerequisites']))
        {
            $data[$delegate->id]['prerequisites'] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            $data[$delegate->id]['prerequisites'] = $unknown['prerequisites'];
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

// Filename: Delegate.php
// Selection: 1
public function storeDelegates($contactData, $unknownData, $eventId, $bookingId)
{
    $delegates = array();
    if (!is_null($contactData))
    {
        foreach ($contactData as $contact)
        {
            $delegate = $this->create(array('contact_id' => $contact['contact_id'], 'unknown_id' => '0'));
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['delegate_status_id'] = $contact['delegate_status_id'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['price'] = $contact['price'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['prerequisites'] = $contact['prerequisites'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['booking_id'] = $bookingId;
        } 
    }

    if (!is_null($unknownData))
    {
        foreach ($unknownData as $unknown)
        {
            $delegate = $this->create(array('contact_id' => '0', 'unknown_id' => $unknown['unknown_id']));
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['delegate_status_id'] = $unknown['delegate_status_id'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['price'] = $unknown['price'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['prerequisites'] = $unknown['prerequisites'];
            $delegates[$delegate->id]['booking_id'] = $bookingId;
        }  
    }

    return $delegates;
}

// Filename: Event.php
// Selection: 1
public function syncDelegates($eventId, $delegates)
{
    $event = $this->find($eventId);
    return $event->delegates()->sync($delegates);
}
```

When adding multiple unknown delegates the resulting $delegates array looks something like:

```
array(3) {
    [1] array(4) {
        ["delegate_status_id"] "2"
        ["price"] 250
        ["prerequisites"] "on"
        ["booking_id"] NULL
    }
    [2] array(4) {
        ["delegate_status_id"] "2"
        ["price"] 250
        ["prerequisites"] "on"
        ["booking_id"] NULL
    }
    [3] array(4) {
        ["delegate_status_id"] "2"
        ["price"] 250
        ["prerequisites"] "on"
        ["booking_id"] NULL
    }
}
```

Again, this works fine when passed to the sync method. It stores all the correct delegate relationships on the pivot table.

When storing a single unknown delegate, the $delegates array looks like:

```
array(1) {
    [4] array(4) {
        ["delegate_status_id"] "1"
        ["price"] "3000"
        ["prerequisites"] "on"
        ["booking_id"] NULL
    }
}
```

Again, this works fine once but as soon as you try to add another, it replaces/updates the record with the new ids.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior of Laravel 4: at the end of the `->sync($array)` you will only have the items in the array. [Check here](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) for more details.

You should use a different approach: check if the item is in the collection, otherwise add it.

```
public function syncDelegates($eventId, $delegates){
    $event = $this->find($eventId);
    foreach($delegates as $key => $value){
        if(!$event->delegates->contains($value)){
            $event->delegates()->attach($value);
        }
    }
}
```

This should add the items you are missing

Comment: Hmmm! How come when adding multiples using the exact same code it works fine?

Comment: Ah! Ignore the last message, I see what it means, I missed: "only the IDs in the array will be on the intermediate table for the model"

Comment: Also, not sure this code will work, as I need to attach pivot data to each delegate on the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the pointers, I've added my modified code which now works to my question above. Thanks dude.

Comment: @Gaz no problem. Do you need help with pivot data?

Comment: No thanks mate. I just didn't understand the sync method fully. Thanks though dude.